# Validation with Yup doesn't show the correct message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I'm using [Yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup) and Formik to validate some fields.

One of the must be a number so this is how it was done:

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';

...

const requiredErrorMessage = 'This field is required';
const numberErrorMessage = 'This field is must be numerical';

 const validationSchema = Yup.object({
      anotherField: Yup.string().required(requiredErrorMessage),
      numberField: Yup.number(numberErrorMessage).required(requiredErrorMessage),
 });
```

So I would expect it to show the message "This field is must be numerical" if there are introduced different characters than numbers.

But it doesn't. If I write "a" in the field the message is this: **"price must be a `number` type, but the final value was: `NaN` (cast from the value `"a"`)."**

Why is it showing a different message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a custom message to number type you should call the typeError() function:

```js
numberField: Yup.number().typeError(numberErrorMessage).required(requiredErrorMessage),
```